# angular grid hide when filter the records

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-grid

I am using [angulargrid](https://github.com/s-yadav/angulargrid) and I have products array `$scope.products` and fetch records from database everything is perfect and grid is showing.

When I apply filter like I query records from database and reassign the records to `$scope.products` but grid vanish. So I apply `angularGridInstance.gallery.refresh()` but it not works.

After that I add timeout of 2 seconds and then refresh the grid using `angularGridInstance.gallery.refresh()` in that case grid start showing.

I don't want to add 2 seconds delay everytime when I filter records. Please suggest any better solution.

This is the dropdown from where I am calling filter query

```
<select ng-model="selectedMerchants" id="test" class="ui fluid dropdown" ng-change="filterUpdate(selectedMerchants)">
    <option ng-repeat="s in suppliers" value="{{s.id}}">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is the grid layout

```
<ul class="dynamic-grid" angular-grid="pics" ag-grid-width="300" ag-gutter-size="10" ag-id="handleBarGrid">
   <li class="grid md-whiteframe-2dp" id="product{{p.id}}" ng-repeat="p in products">
     // some data
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is controller logic

```
$scope.filterUpdate = function(){
  var promise = asyncFilterResult(filterUpdateQuery); // filter query which fetch the records from database
  promise.then(function(productsData) {
    $scope.products = productsData;
    angularGridInstance.handleBarGrid.refresh();
    console.log("Success");
  }, function(reason) {
    angularGridInstance.handleBarGrid.refresh();
  });

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what about showing some code?

Comment: @quirimmo I edit my question and add some basic code may be it will helpful.

Comment: after the refresh method, can you try to add a `$scope.$apply()` please?
`angularGridInstance.handleBarGrid.refresh();$scope.$apply();`

Comment: I tried but it gives error

'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress'

Comment: ok so some digest is already in progress. Can you try to set the data from the obtained $scope.products directly? In your case should be something like (I don't know so change the code with your data properly): 
`angularGridInstance.handleBarGrid.data = $scope.products;` ?

Comment: I try but nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145055/discussion-between-qubaish-bhatti-and-quirimmo).